# Maven/Netbean project

Tags: maven, uml, netbeans-7

I've tried Maven plugin to generate class diagram. However, this tool only generate a particular class's diagram. I wonder if there are tool out there to generate an overview class diagram based on the source code I have?

```
<plugin> 
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration> 
                <aggregate>true</aggregate> 
                <show>private</show> 
                <doclet>org.umlgraph.doclet.UmlGraphDoc</doclet> 
                <docletArtifact>                                                         
                    <groupId>org.umlgraph</groupId>                                      
                    <artifactId>umlgraph</artifactId>                                    
                    <version>5.6</version>                                               
                </docletArtifact>        
                <additionalparam> 
                    -views -all -inferrel -collpackages java.util.* -inferdep  -nodefontsize 9 
                </additionalparam>
                <useStandardDocletOptions>true</useStandardDocletOptions> 
            </configuration> 
        </plugin>
```

Comment: in the end, I've used Eclipse with ObjectAid plugin (more info at http://www.objectaid.com/).